# Spoonacular API being called multiple times when implemented via RX Java in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java

I am learning implementation of Rx Java in Kotlin via MVVM architecture. I have a simple app that takes input from the user regarding the name of a dish like 'pasta' , 'pizza' etc and subsequently on press of a button , I call Spoonacular Api via Rx java to display the name of the dish returned by the API call , in the logcat.

Now every time I press the button, the number of call increases by two and I receive multiple names every time. Can someone please guide me in this.

**Spoonacular Api Data Class ( It is a very big class hence I have just included the important part)** ->

```
object FilteredDishes {

    data class DishesFromAPI(
        val recipes: List<Recipe>
    )

    data class Recipe(
        val aggregateLikes: Int,
        val analyzedInstructions: List<AnalyzedInstruction>,
        val cheap: Boolean,
.....
```

**Interface Code** ->

```
interface DishInterface {

    @GET(Constants.spoonacularEndPoint)
    fun getDishes(
        @Query(Constants.apiKey) apiKey : String,
        @Query(Constants.limitLicense) limitLicense : Boolean,
        @Query(Constants.tags) tags : String,
        @Query(Constants.number) number : Int
    ) : Single<FilteredDishes.DishesFromAPI>
}
```

**Retrofit builder Code** ->

```
class DishApiService {

    private val api=Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Constants.spoonacularBaseURL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(DishInterface::class.java)

    fun getDishFromInternet(type:String) : Single<FilteredDishes.DishesFromAPI> {
        return api.getDishes(Constants.spoonacularAPiKeyValue,false,type,1)
    }
}
```

**View Model code** ->

```
class DishApiViewModel : ViewModel(){

    private val dishApiService : DishApiService = DishApiService()
    private val compositeDisposable : CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    val loadDish = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val dishResponse = MutableLiveData<FilteredDishes.DishesFromAPI>()
    val dishLoadingError = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

    fun getRecipesFromAPI(filter:String){
        loadDish.value=true

        compositeDisposable.add(
            dishApiService.getDishFromInternet(filter)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(object : DisposableSingleObserver<FilteredDishes.DishesFromAPI>(){
                    override fun onSuccess(value: FilteredDishes.DishesFromAPI?) {
                        loadDish.value=false
                        dishResponse.value=value!!
                        dishLoadingError.value=false
                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Throwable?) {
                        loadDish.value=false
                        dishLoadingError.value=true
                        e!!.printStackTrace()
                    }

                })
        )
    }
}
```

**XML File** ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.SearchFragment">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_16sdp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/clcick"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_200sdp"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/et"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Fragment Code** ->

```
class SearchFragment : Fragment() {

    private var mBinding: FragmentSearchBinding? = null

    private lateinit var mDishApiViewModel : DishApiViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        mBinding = FragmentSearchBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return mBinding!!.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        mDishApiViewModel= ViewModelProvider(this)[DishApiViewModel::class.java]

        mBinding!!.btn.setOnClickListener{
            if(mBinding!!.et.text.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Please enter dish type", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }else{
                apiCall(mBinding!!.et.text.toString())
            }
        }
    }

    
    private fun apiCall(filter:String){
        mDishApiViewModel.getRecipesFromAPI(filter)
        dishViewModelObserver()
    }

    private fun dishViewModelObserver(){
        mDishApiViewModel.dishResponse.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,
            {
                if(it!=null){
                    if(it.recipes.isNotEmpty()){
                        Log.e("Response", it.recipes[0].title)
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }

            })

        mDishApiViewModel.dishLoadingError.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,
            {
                if(it!=null){
                    Log.e("loadingError","$it")
                }
            }

        )

        mDishApiViewModel.loadDish.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,
            {
                if(it!=null){
                    Log.e("load","$it")
                }
            })

    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        mBinding = null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you call `dishViewModelObserver` and every time you add yet another observer to the observers list of your `LiveData`.

You need to move that function from `apiCall` to `onViewCreated`:

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    mDishApiViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[DishApiViewModel::class.java]

    dishViewModelObserver()
    mBinding!!.btn.setOnClickListener{
        if (mBinding!!.et.text.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Please enter dish type", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            apiCall(mBinding!!.et.text.toString())
        }
    }
}
    
private fun apiCall(filter: String) {
    mDishApiViewModel.getRecipesFromAPI(filter)
}
```

Tip: you also need to get rid of he habit of using `m` prefixes, this convention was added to Java to differentiate property types, but in Kotlin getter and setter JVM functions are generated for your properties.

I.e. in Java

```
void setThing(thing: Thing) {
    mThing = thing
}
```

made some sense over

```
void setThing(thing: Thing) {
    this.Thing = thing
}
```